# No puedo Establecer Foco Un Form Java SE

Tags: java

Gracias Por la ayuda tengo un formulario en java al abrirlo me asigna el foco al primer jtextfield ,he intentenado con requestfocus() despues de initComponents(); pero nada siempre abre el foco en el primer jtextfield tambien lei que grabfocus y nada como cambio el orden que da netbeans a los jtextfield el los asigna de acuerdo a su creacion y quiero que arranque con foco en el quinto jtextfiel muchas gracias

Coloco el inicio por que no alcanzo todo por limitacion caracteres

public class Factura extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

```
private Control ctrl;
/////instanciar fefcha
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();
String dia;
String mes;
String annio;
DefaultTableModel ingresar;
/** Creates new form Factura */
```

//  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Factura(Control ctrl) {

```
    dia = Integer.toString(c2.get(Calendar.DATE));
    mes = Integer.toString(c2.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    annio = Integer.toString(c2.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    initComponents();
    Dimension tamFrame=this.getSize();
    Dimension tamPantalla=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); 
    setLocation((tamPantalla.width-tamFrame.width)/2, (tamPantalla.height-tamFrame.height)/12);
    this.ctrl = ctrl;
    this.setTitle("Registro de Ventas ");
    //Se obtiene el nombre del cliente
    txtName.setText( ctrl.getNameCliente() );
    ID.setText( ctrl.getIdCliente() );
     //vis.setVisible(false);
    salir.setVisible(false);

    //se genera un codigo Random para Numero de factura
    txtNumFactura.setText( ctrl.GenerarNumFactura() );
    txtVendedor.getText();   

     Date fechaActual = new Date();
     DateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     String fechast = formatoFecha.format(fechaActual);
     txtFecha.setText( fechast );

    btnUpObs.setVisible(false);


  ////////// Completar Codigo
TextAutoCompleter textAutoCompleter = new TextAutoCompleter(codigob);
String sql="";
sql="SELECT * FROM producto ";
String []datos = new String [1];
 try {
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            datos[0]=rs.getString(1);
            textAutoCompleter.addItem(datos[0]=rs.getString(1));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ingresoproductos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    /////////  Completar Nombre
 TextAutoCompleter Nombre = new TextAutoCompleter(pName);
String sqln="";
sqln="SELECT * FROM producto ";
String []datosn = new String [2];
 try {
        Statement stn = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsn = stn.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rsn.next()){
            datosn[1]=rsn.getString(2);
            Nombre.addItem(datosn[1]=rsn.getString(2));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ingresoproductos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }  


}
```

Comment: Para entender mejor la pregunta editala y pon todo el código

Comment: ok gracias por la ayuda ya coloco el codigo de inicio del form

Comment: Ya lo solucione era in jinternalframe por eso no funcionaba le hice lo siguiente SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                      codigob.requestFocus();
                }
          });